# How to select few cells from row and show them in a column?

Tags: mysql, sql, select

Let's say that I have a badly designed table or even not.
It looks like this:

```
+-----+---------+---------+---------+----------
| id  | value 1 | value 2 | value 3 | others...
+-----+---------+---------+---------+----------
| 1   | 1v1     | 1v2     | 1v3     | sth
+-----+---------+---------+---------+----------
| 2   | 2v1     | 2v2     | 2v3     | sth
+-----+---------+---------+---------+----------
```

And now I'd like to select value 1, value 2, value 3 from this table and show it in column.
This is the expected output:

```
+----+--------+
| id | val    |
+----+--------+
| 1  | 1v1    |
+----+--------+
| 1  | 1v2    |
+----+--------+
| 1  | 1v3    |
+----+--------+
| 2  | 2v1    |
+----+--------+
| 2  | 2v2    |
+----+--------+
| 2  | 2v3    |
+----+--------+
```

Any ideas how to do it?

Comment: Are you trying to do this purely in MySQL? Or within a coding project?

Comment: Pure SQL. Answer below is perfect for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT id, `value 1` AS val
FROM your_table
UNION ALL
SELECT id, `value 2` AS val
FROM your_table
UNION ALL
...
```

and so on for all columns necessary. You might want to use `UNION` instead of `UNION ALL`. It removes duplicates.